# Law In CA for driving with expired registration

Tags: united-states, california

Okay I can’t seem to find what I’m looking for. Everything comes up as expired tags when searching for expired registration. My tags are good through this month. I only have expired registration, I also have insurance. So what happens if I am pulled over? Am I subject to removal of vehicle and getting searched with no right to deny a search? Or is it a simple fine and on my way?

Comment: Hello Firefighter1.  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our tour page, which is linked at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I believe not having current registration is a violation of CVC 4000(a)(1). I don't have the answers to the rest of your questions.